# Text to HTML conversion without *any* formatting

Tags: shell, text-to-html

I want to convert the output of a shell command to HTML, regardless of what the command prints.
I've tried using txt2html and pandoc but the first will not keep lines of hypens, even with the --nounhipenation param, and also formatting tags like < h1 > to some lines.

with txt2html this output:

```
TEST: SimpleTest
-----------------------------------
 All test completed in 1ms
 Warning: No asserts run!
 All assert(s) passed.
-----------------------------------
```

becomes:

```
<h1>TEST: SimpleTest</h1>
<p> All test completed in 1ms<br/>
 Warning: No asserts run!<br/>
 All assert(s) passed.
</p><hr/>
```

Notice the missing hypens and the spurious < h1 > < /h1 > and for some reason < hr/ > tags.

I would like it to output something like:

```
<p>TEST: SimpleTest<br/>
-----------------------------------<br/>
 All test completed in 1ms<br/>
 Warning: No asserts run!<br/>
 All assert(s) passed.
-----------------------------------<br/>
</p>
```

Comment: Why can't you just use sed for this?

Comment: Scaping the odd characters like áÁéóú and sed seems to have a grudge replacing newlines with stream input. If you happen to know how to do this with sed post a solution please :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before and the following has worked for me.

http://2partsmagic.com/util/text2html.jsp

Comment: While this solution works, I'm trying to make the conversion inside a shell script, probably offline for weeks, so webpages are a no-go.